# How to spawn process multiple directories in perl

Tags: perl

I have a set of directories parsing it in foreach and writing the each directories processing output to same file. I am trying to use this fork process method. however, it doesn't work properly and it writes one by one foreach directory process.

Please suggest how to spawn the process individual directories either write into same file or different files.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my $totalcount  = "/tmp/count";
my @dirs = qw(List of Dirs);
open(FL, ">", "$totalcount");

foreach my $dir (@dirs) {
    my $pid;
    next if $pid = fork;    
    die "fork failed: $!" unless defined $pid;
    processing here...
    print FL "$count";
    exit;
}

1 while (wait() != -1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/~yanick/Parallel-ForkManager/) for such purpose.

```
# spawn 8 processes at a time
my $parallelForkManager = new Parallel::ForkManager(8);
foreach my $dir (@dirs) {
    $parallelForkManager->start and next;

    # processing here...

    $parallelForkManager->finish;
}
$parallelForkManager->wait_all_children;
```

If you want to access to a single file from multiple processes, you may need exclusive access control over it.

```
open (FILE, '>>', $path);
flock(FILE, LOCK_EX);
print FILE $data;
close FILE;
```

However, it seems that `flock` varies on different operating systems. Please look for other information sources about `flock` issue.

---

**EDIT**:

If you want to handle a file per directory open and write it in the for-each:

```
foreach my $dir (@dirs) {
    $parallelForkManager->start and next;

    # processing here...

    open (FILE, '>', "$dir/$filename");
    print FILE $data;
    close FILE;

    $parallelForkManager->finish;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: is there a way output from foreach directory can write to individual file instead of append mode or can I write to single file for each directory execution ?. I'll be replacing the values written on that file on next time run. hence , I am not using the append mode. thank you

Comment: @organic '>>' is for example. You can do some process you want in the for-each (`# processing here...`). Updated my answer.

Comment: thanks. now, it spawn the process. however it seems it waiting  for children process to complete as it is writing to a single file. also,  it waits for few seconds and writes to file  as like single process. Not sure if I am missing anything. I've removed that wait_for_children already.

Comment: @organic Your perl is compiled as multi-thread? If so, there may remain some bottle neck of performance with OS or hardware (file access is rather heavy job), I don't know any more...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion so far. I'll debug the issue

Answer (score 0):

You have an answer for how to do it, but I'll suggest it's not actually going to help much. Parallelism helps when you've got multiple CPUs and are able to use them parallel.

However for directory traversal, you don't really gain very much by doing so - either it's already cached (and so there's no need) or it isn't and all you do is thrash your disks.

Comment: Thanks Sobrque for your hint.